# How to restrict access to user detail's pages where role is higher than them?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make my program secure by not allowing users to just type in the id number so they can see other users.

Users with access level 1 may only see their own details, but level 2's can see their own details and level 1's

The if statement works but not the elif

```
if session["AccessLevel"] == 1 and str(user_id) != str(session["UserId"]):
        flash("You may only view your own details")
        return redirect("/details?id=" + str(session["UserId"]))    

elif session["AccessLevel"] == 2 and str(user_id["AccessLevel"]) == 3:
        flash("You may not view admin details")
        return redirect("/details?id=" + str(session["UserId"]))
```

Comment: the elif statement doesn't work. How it doesn't, is there any error or the statement is not executed please give full detail so that we can figure out the problem. see SO question asking [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @charchit TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: user_id is str, as you defined it in comment below on @Ayse answer's. If you are sending AccesLevel from html to flask as get request then use `request.args.get("AcessLevel")`

Comment: @charchit I added `access = request.args.get["AccessLevel"]` and I got TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You have used square brackets ,see `()` in code line above. Use curved brackets

Comment: @charchit i tried `access = request.args.get("AccessLevel")` and then `if session["AccessLevel"] == 2 and str(access) == 3:` but nothing is happening. Not even an error but I can still see level 3 users

Comment: Are you sure you are sending AccessLevel to flask , try printing access before if statement

Comment: @charchit It printed `None`

Comment: Can you please show your html and what really you want access to be. Where do you get the acessLevel from.

Answer (score 0):

What does the user_id property return? dict or something?

```
str(user_id) != str(session["UserId"]) # if user_id type is not dict ok
str(user_id["AccessLevel"]) # if user_id type is dict ok
```

If you can check your data type you can handle that i think.

Comment: `user_id = request.args.get("id")`